# Print days (name) by an array from database

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this 0,0,0,0,1,1,0 - that means two days are selected by an entry. the days are Friday and Saturday.

How can I replace the "1" values of this array by day? The outpz must be "Fr, Sa"?
Sorry for my bad english:)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$days = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
$dayNames = array("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su");
$daysText = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dayNames); ++$i) {
    if ($days[$i] === 1) {
        $daysText .= $dayNames[$i] . ", ";
    }
}
$daysText = rtrim($daysText, ", ");

echo $daysText;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$days = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
$dayNames = array("Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su");

$openDays = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_combine(
            $dayNames,
            $days
        )
    )
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/mYmNF3)

And you can then simply

```
echo implode(', ', $openDays);
```

Comment: when I put that all in a function and passing the array $days eg. $days = array($passingarray); the output is empty!?

Comment: If you're getting an empty result from your function, then you're doing something wrong in your function, or when calling the function

Comment: I have to split the array which comes from database eg: $days = split(",",$array); so the array value will be outputed... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many ways to do it in php.

```
   $days = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
   $flags= array(0,0,0,0,1,1,0);

    for($x=0; $x<count($days); $x++){
        if($flags[$x] == 1)
            echo $days[$x];
    }
```

This uses the idea of parallel arrays. Iterate through the flags, if it is 1, based of that index of flag, print the respective day in text.